# How to get simulator to work in XCode 4.3.1?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3, ios5.1

I am currently unable to get the simulator (5.0 and 5.1) to run. I thought it could have been an issue with my code, but a brand new project (straight from the templates) compiles just fine and then hangs when it looks like the debugger attempts to hook into the simulator. Is anyone else experiencing this, and if so, have they found a work around?

11222336

**Edit -**
I decided to go ahead and file a bug report for this issue:[11222336](https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/35/wo/6Ro86wRnPgWpfTDGsz1Tcw/14.66)

Comment: Well, I have tried the standard Xcode fixes of cleaning builds, restarting Xcode, validating settings. What has me very confused about this is the standard templates for new projects, before I have added in any code, will not run in the simulator.

Comment: Yeah, that is pretty odd. This seems to be a common problem when people upgrade to 4.3.1. Check the downloads section of Xcode preferences. It should let you select the simulators you want to install.

Comment: I already made sure of that as well. I have iOS 5.0 simulator and iOS 4.3 simulator downloaded and installed. I do not have the command line tools installed though, going to see if that makes any difference. Don't think it will :\

Comment: Yep, no dice. Xcode still beach balled on me at the same point.

Comment: Well I'm sorry to say, it sounds like you need a reinstall.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the machine. Sometimes the debugger will not run for me saying the app is still running and only a restart 'cures' it.

Comment: @JavierC Sadly, I get no reports at all from the debugger. The debugger is unable to launch, so Xcode just hangs. Eventually the app quits trying to run in the simulator but Xcode is left frozen. Guess I'll try a reinstall next :\

Comment: Yep, reinstall did not fix the issue either. Looks like I'll be filing a bug report with Apple.

Comment: I believe it may have been fixed in Xcode 4.3.2...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on 2 machines with freshly installed XCode. I filed a bug, which you can see here: http://openradar.appspot.com/11033943

Comment: Thank you. Hopefully they'll fix this issue soon.

Comment: I hadn't tried that in a while, but sadly, the problem still persists. The issue I am running into might be slightly different than the one you encountered, I get no error message. Nothing. Just an app hang when the debugger attempts to spin up.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, delete or rename your /Developer folder, fixes it.

Comment: /Developer no longer exists, at least without doing anything special (like turning on hidden files). Has Apple gone and hidden that directory from us as well?